# showing error when i want to debug the project in c#

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, build

When I want to build the project then it is showing the following error, how to resolve from this?

> Error  1   Unable to write manifest 'obj\x64\Debug\Speech.exe.manifest'. Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
>   error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\gev2gqyi.0.cs' could not be found
>   error CS2008: No inputs specified

Comment: i don't know what type of error it is. But please suggest the right step what to do.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Unable to write manifest" indicates that the system is having trouble actually writing the output file which is going into the temp folder. This can happen if you do not have sufficient privileges to write to the temp folder. Make sure that you have write permission for the C:\Windows\TEMP\ folder.